# wxWidgets jpeg library build issue

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, wxwidgets, building

I'm trying to build wxWidgets library into a custom path on a Fedora 27 operative system.

I achieved the `wx-config` file path recognition and works with the cmake execution. Also, I load libraries and include dirs based on modified wxWidgets finder cmake file that sets the`wx-config` custom path successfully.

But cmake does not load my wxWidgets configuration. I mean, `wx_gtk2u_jpeg-3.1` builded lib could not be founded (suposed to be `/usr/lib/libwx_gtk2u_jpeg-3.1.so`). I need `jpeg` dependency from wxWidgets for my project.

I'm sure that problem is not about cmake files. However, the problem is wxWidgets compilation because cmake can found the other builded dependencies into `/usr/lib/`

I actually installed the `libjpeg-turbo-devel` package that includes the `libjpeg.h` needed for wxWidgets building without success of `libwx_gtk2u_jpeg-3.1.so` creation.

The weirdest part is that `$ wx-config --libs` shows the `wx_gtk2u_jpeg-3.1` lib to be linked and the hint paths that it should be founded.

wxWidgets commands for building:

```
$ ./configure --with-libjpeg=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --with-libtiff=builtin --with-zlib=builtin --with-expat=builtin --enable-webviewwebkit=no --prefix=/opt/cpp_dependencies/2018Q1/usr'
$ make -j 4
$ make install
```

You can check out my cmake files, the cmake output and wxWidgets building output in order to reproducing it: https://gist.github.com/jjalvarezl/b70accae269ef56c56010bedf157c27f

You can see line 1543 of wxWidgets building output file that jpeg library is `buildin`, and, 1564 of same file, the `make install` command that installs all `libwx_<lib_name>.so` libraries into final `/usr/lib` path. Anyway, no one contains the needed library.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the exact error message, as it's not clear what the actual problem is. What I can say, is that the different built-in versions of 3rd party libraries, such as libjpeg, are *always* static libraries, even when wxWidgets themselves are shared. I.e. you're never going to have `libwx_gtk2u_jpeg-3.1.so`, only `.a`.

I'd also strongly recommend using system versions of the 3rd party libraries under Unix systems. This means that your wxWidgets applications will get security updates from your OS vendor and you don't risk running into any incompatibilities due to using 2 different versions of the same library in your application.

Comment: The error appears on cmake output, line 11: `wxWidgets not found due to following missing libraries: wx_gtk2u_jpeg-3.1`. My cmake project works with libraries with a specific version due to compatibility issues.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about where does this error message come from. The canonical way to link with wxWidgets under Unix is to use `$(wx-config --libs)` output and it really should work.